# What does it mean 'to shoot oneself in the foot'?

Tags: metaphors, phrase-meaning

In the First World War soldiers in the trenches on both sides would sometimes give themselves a non-fatal wound ( intentionally shooting themselves in the foot, whilst making it appear as an accident, being a favourite). The purpose was to get themselves medically repatriated and out of the way of possible more serious harm, or death in action.

Often I hear people use the term 'he has shot himself in the foot' to refer to someone who has  unintentionally harmed his own interests whilst in the process of trying to damage someone else.

What is the understood meaning of the metaphor 'to shoot oneself in the foot'?

Comment: I should think [this meaning](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+oneself+in+the+foot) carries from here to Manchester. [Quinion](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sho4.htm) acknowledges that there may well have been a semantic shift. Or two.

Comment: *To put your foot in it* is very similar in meaning, isn't it?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Interesting material. Yes it smells of semantic shift to me too.

Comment: @Mari-Lou No! See Edwin's comment and follow the link.

Comment: [to say something by accident which embarrasses or upsets someone I really put my foot in it with Julie. I didn't realise she was a vegetarian.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+foot+in+it) perhaps it's just a poor relation :) But I do see a connection of sorts.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Well they both contain the word 'foot', I suppose. However the original meaning of 'shooting in the foot' appears per Edwin Ashworth to have changed significantly over the years. In a similar vein I was researching a late-eighteenth-century writer who had included some commentary on Machiavelli. What I discovered was that interpretations of Machiavelli had changed dramatically over the centuries. The 17th century Machiavelli is a quite different animal to the 18th and the 19th-century philosopher, and different again to the way we understand him today.

Comment: @WS2 I thought I'd corrected the allusion to Manchester to one to Berkshire (implying that the meaning I'm familiar with is almost certainly not restricted to Oldham). It loses the little humour it had with the additional miles the geographical shift necessitates  - but on checking, I see that it's your grandson who you say lives (or lived) here in the NW. (And yes, I remember the olde catchphrase.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Currently in the course of two weeks child-minding in sunny Burnage, so Manchester was quite appropriate as it happened.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why don't you post the Quinion link as an answer? I would be happy to accept it as the "correct" one.

Comment: World Wide Words is, as I understand it, regarded as a [commonly-available resource questioners should themselves have checked in](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/484/common-accepted-online-resources).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If every questioner does exhaustive research before they have the temerity to engage on the site, I feel pretty sure the traffic would diminish from the Thames to a trickle.

Comment: But a trickle of liquid gold. And there's already been a lot of pre-Bazelgette  water under the bridge.

Comment: Note for future readers: this is not to be confused with "[he/she] shot to [his/her] feet" which is a different idiom (and the one I was researching while I ended up here).

Answer (score 2):

The *Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms* says

> **shoot yourself in the foot** *inadvertently make a situation
> worse for yourself; demonstrate gross incompetence*

*The Free Dictionary* online has

> Fig. to cause oneself difficulty; to be the author of one's own
> misfortune. *I am a master at shooting myself in the foot. Again, he
> shot himself in the foot by saying too much to the press.*

*The Chambers Dictionary* has this pithy definition

> *(inf) to harm one's own interests by ineptitude*

The original meaning of either accidentally shooting yourself in the foot with a gun or deliberately avoiding military combat by self inflicting a severe wound seems to have been lost or fogotten.

Perhaps the idiom, *to shoot oneself in the foot*, has overtaken a much older saying which has slowly grown out of favour and is becoming obsolete.

[**Hoist with own petard**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hoist+with+own+petard)
*Fig. to be harmed or disadvantaged by an action of one's own which was meant to harm someone else. Based on the literal meaning of hoist by your own petard; blown into the air by your own explosive device. (From a line in Shakespeare's Hamlet.)*

```
There's letters seal'd: and my two schoolfellows,
Whom I will trust as I will adders fang'd,
They bear the mandate; they must sweep my way
And marshal me to knavery. Let it work;
For 'tis the sport to have the enginer
Hoist with his own petar'; and 't shall go hard
But I will delve one yard below their mines
And blow them at the moon: O, 'tis most sweet,
When in one line two crafts directly meet
```

The Free Dictionary gives the following examples of usage. It seems to me, at least, that the meaning is very similar to "shoot oneself in the foot".

> She intended to murder her brother but was **hoist with her own petard** when
> she ate the poisoned food intended for him.
>
> The vandals were **hoist with their own petard** when they tried to make an emergency call from
> the pay phone they had broken.

Comment: What you identified here was the way the idiom is frequently and incorrectly used. 'Shooting oneself in the foot' was a deliberate act in order to get oneself medically repatriated.

Comment: @WS2 What makes you believe your meaning is the original? Do you have anydata showing this idiom ever been used in your meaning? Do you know when it first appeared? You can easily shoot yourself unintentionally when manipulating a gun wrong.

Comment: @VladimirF I'm not saying it was used as an idiom. But there are certainly [recorded instances of soldiers having deliberately shot themselves in the foot](http://spartacus-educational.com/FWWblighty.htm). The fact that it could easily happen accidentally doubtless was a reason why they would chose that method of injuring themselves. The metaphor as it is used today has a different meaning. But you may be right - the idiom (with different meaning) may pre-date the practice. But somehow I doubt it.

Comment: @VladimirF After consideration I believe Edwin Ashworth has supplied the best explanation with his Quinion link above. No, I fully admit that I have no way of knowing which meaning is the original - which lies behind my asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

"Shoot yourself in the foot" comes from the old west, when a cowboy wore his pistol in a belt holster.  If he tried to draw too quickly the gun may accidentally go off before he gets it out of the holster, resulting in a foot being shot.

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion. But to be complete the answer really requires some referencing. I believe the "Quinion" link supplied by Edwin Ashworth provides the most comprehensive explanation here, and I am encouraging him to supply it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To shoot yourself in the foot is to mess yourself up. To cause difficulty to yourself on pure accident.

Comment: It is a significantly more complex matter than that, Jonathan. May I suggest you follow Edwin Ashworth's hyperlinks above. They are quite instructive.

Comment: That first link is where I got that definition, except I searched for that link. The second link is very informative. I see now.