# A person who creates problems for himself

Tags: meaning

What is the definition of a person who creates problems for himself?
I already tried slumpy trumpy trouble maker.

Comment: Can you provide more context or an example?

Answer (score 3):

I would certainly not use "slumpy trumpy trouble maker" unless you're talking to a toddler.

You might say the person [**shot themselves in the foot**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=shoot%20yourself%20in%20the%20foot):

> inadvertently make a situation worse for oneself.

See also: [What does it mean 'to shoot oneself in the foot'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137187/what-does-it-mean-to-shoot-oneself-in-the-foot)

Answer (score 1):

Other expressions that might apply are:

"to make a rod for your own back", and

"to be hoist by your own petard" (a primitive bomb)